# CAS - Binary Tree Alternative

Tags: math, binary-tree, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

Is there a **reasonable** way to make an entire **Computer Algebra System** (algebraic equations, limits, derivatives, integrals) without using binary trees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maple uses a [Directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG). The is still a tree-like structure with nodes and links however two nodes can have the same child if they have common subexpressions. Binary trees are a special case of DAG's which are a special type of graph.

*Binary* trees are actually a bit restrictive. You often want to have a different number of children for each node: unitary operators like -x, functions with various numbers of arguments. An integral will need four children: the integrand, top and bottom limits and the variable the integral is wrt.

If you know your elements are going to be of a specific type then other data types might be more appropriate. For example if you are dealing with polynomials then multidimensional arrays might be more appropriate. So 2 x^2 + 3 x - 7 might be represented as [7,3,2].

For a general purpose system I don't think you could get away from some graph like structure.